# How to set content type with Logstash & rabbitmq output?

Tags: json, rabbitmq, content-type, logstash

I want to parse logs with logstash and sends the results via rabbitmq. The application using these results is waiting for a message with content_type set to "application/json". For now, my messages have no properties and my application is not able to process the message.

Could you please tell me how logstash sends a message to rabbitmq with a property "content_type" set to "application/json"?

Thanks beforehand & best regards,

Romain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is currently not possible. I've filed [github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-rabbitmq bug #6](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-rabbitmq/issues/6) for you.

Until that bug has been addressed, perhaps you can write a simple microservice that consumes the content-type-less messages and republishes them on another topic, exchange, or queue with the correct content type declare.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Magnus Bäck said, it's not possible out of the box. But if you really need it, you can fork rabbitmq plugin. And add something like `:content_type => 'application/json'` to [this line](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-rabbitmq/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/rabbitmq/march_hare.rb#L40)